# Why won't this Haskell type coercion compile?

Tags: haskell, casting

Ugh. The following code fails to compile:

```
factorsOf number = [(x, quot number x) | x <- [2..toInteger $ floor $ sqrt number], number `mod` x == 0]
```

The following error is thrown:

- "No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of `sqrt'"

Please help? I'm clearly not grokking Haskell coercion.

PS: Leaving off `toInteger` compiles but throws a type-ambiguity error at runtime.

Comment: `floor` takes a non-integer and returns an integer, no extra motions to do. `sqrt` on the other hand can’t take an integer, it’s the very first step that breaks.

Comment: @FrownyFrog Omg. I *knew* I was being dense. Could you please make this an answer so's I can accept it?

Comment: *type-ambiguity error at runtime* there's no such thing in Haskell.

Comment: @n.m. Oh. Then I guess I mean whatever error is indicated by "Ambiguous type variable 'b0' arising from a use of 'print' prevents the constraint '(Show b0)' from being solved."

Comment: That's a compile time error about `print`.

Comment: @n.m. Oh, gotcha. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is highly advisable to always start design of a Haskell function with the *type signature*, and only then write the implementation. In this case, you probably want

```
factorsOf :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
```

So, within `factorsOf n = ...`, the variable `n` will have type `Integer`. That's the problem: you're trying to take the square root of an integer, but `sqrt` is only defined on floating numbers. So you need to convert to such a number *before* taking the root. After the root, you'll then want to truncate back to an integer, but `floor` already does that. `toInteger` is not needed.

```
factorsOf :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
factorsOf n
     = [ (x, n`quot`x)
       | x <- [2 .. floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral n]
       , n `mod` x == 0
       ]
```